# Calculating marginal effects for a weighted logit model

Tags: r, logistic-regression, glm

I calculated a weighted logit model with the "survey" package.

```
 library(survey)

 Mod_design <- svrepdesign(variables = Data,
                    weights = weights,
                    repweights = REP_WGT,
                    type = "JKn",
                    scale = 1,       
                    rscales = 1)

 Mod <- svyglm(Education ~ 
                 Sex + Age + Edu_Parents, 
                 family = quasibinomial, design = Mod_design)
```

Now I would like to calculate marginal effects for this model. Without weights, I would usually use the logitmfx function of the mfx package. Unfortunately, it is not possible to calculate marginal effects for weighted models with this package and so far I couldn't find a way how I could handle this problem.

Is there a way how I could calculate marginal effects for weighted models?

Comment: This might be a CrossValidated question because you're going to have to know how to calculate these given there's probably no out-of-the-box solution in R.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can obtain marginal effects from models estimated via `svyglm` from the R package `survey` using the following code:

```
summary(margins(MODEL_NAME, variables = "VARIABLE_OF_INTEREST", design=YOUR_DESIGN))
```

Comment: Thanks for reactivating this thread and for the answer!